# How to define HTML symbol for special char like Natural join: &#8904;

Tags: html

I use Markdown and HTML for my lecture notes, and when I need an unusual character like Natural join I have to use the unmemorable code &#8904; (⋈).  Is there any way I can define a symbol, like &MYNATJOIN; in a CSS file (or wherever) that would be replaced with the ⋈ at HTML rendering time?

ccp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the character “⋈” as such in HTML, provided that you use UTF-8 and declare it properly, as you should anyway; see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Alternatively, much less reliably, you can use the [HTML5 character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references) `&bowtie;`. It belongs to the added named references that are completely unnecessary and are not supported by any browser version older than 2011.

In order to define your own entitiy that you could use as `&MYNATJOIN;`, you would need to serve your document with an XML content type, which means that old versions of IE will choke on it and that it will be processed in Draconian mode (i.e., any violation of XML well-formedness constraints will cause just an error message to be shown to users, no document content). Under these conditions, you can use XML entity declarations.

CSS is for optional presentational suggestions and should not be used to add significant content, due to the [CSS caveats](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css-caveats.html). If you would use  “⋈” for decorative purposes or to visually highlight something that is already duly emphasized verbally or in markup, you can add it to the rendering using [generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), e.g.

```
.funny:after { content: " ⋈" }
```

in order to append a space and the “⋈” character to the content of every element in class `funny`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a small javascript to the top of your document to do a global replace on your "user defined entity with the entity you want it to refer to. This function runs when the document is loaded.

**JS** (In `<head>` tag)

```
window.onload=function () {
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML
       .replace(/&amp;MYNATJOIN;/gi,"&#8904;");
};
```

**HTML** (In `<body>` tag)

```
these are some notes. <br />
the entity &MYNATJOIN; should now be a bowtie
```

You can define more entites by adding more replace statements

See the code snippet below:

```js
window.onload=function () {
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&amp;MYNATJOIN;/gi,"&#8904;");
    
        console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&amp;PLUSMINUS;/gi,"&#8723;");
    
        console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&amp;SINEWAVE;/gi,"&#8767;");
};
```

```html
<body>
these are some notes.<br />
the entity &MYNATJOIN; should now be a bowtie <br />
a plus or minus looks like this &PLUSMINUS; <br />and how about a sine wave? &SINEWAVE;
</body>
```

Note that:

1. There are a litany of ways to trigger javascript to run when a document has loaded, but `window.onload` is simple and gets the job done.
2. The replacement uses a regular expression as that is a requirement for doing a global string replace in javascript.
3. Any `&` in an HTML document are implicitly converted to `&amp;` by the HTML parser.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<span class='mynatjoin'><span/>
```

**CSS**

```
.mynatjoin:before{
    content: "\22C8";
}
```

**Result**

```
⋈
```

## [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0rz2ax6/)

---

If you want it to be even simpler, and your willing to break your HTML validity, you could use tags, instead of classes like this:

**HTML**

```
<mynatjoin />
```

**CSS**

```
mynatjoin:before{
    content: "\22C8";
}
```

**Result**

```
⋈
```

## [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvranLb2/)

I dont know if this will cause problems in some browsers, but I tested this in the latest, Chrome, FF an IE. It worked. Probably wont work in older browsers.

If you want to do it the way you specified i.e `&MYNATJOIN;`, then you will need to use some sort of javascript which scans the document and replaces `&MYNATJOIN;` with `⋈`. I don't think it is possible with pure html and css

Based on the example above, you can have multiple css classes to support your symbols. [You can use this](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) to find the css code for your corresponding symbol.

Comment: In addition to using `span` as “self-closing”, against HTML specifications, this approach means that *nothing* appears when CSS is disabled.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Well true about the span. I corrected that. And  also who in the 21st century would disable CSS? I mean if someone is willing to disable CSS, they would already understand the drawbacks... and such people would comprise of less than 1% of a sites traffic

Comment: The answer still has invalid HTML markup, and it still recommends an approach that relies on CSS with no apparent reason.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I gave an answer in CSS because that's what OP asked for. And what is it that is still invalid HTML?